# Maintaining object state across activities

Tags: android

I have activity A where I have a List of Objects of type URL (with a method like() ).

I load these URL objects in a recyclerview User clicks on the item and I open another activity which opens detailed view in Activity B where user can press a button which calls "like" method on the URL object.

When the user closes the Activity B I want the recyclerview of A to reflect this changes state.

How exactly is this achieved in Android ?

Comment: Use `onActivityResult()` to show changes made in data set from another activity.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of use cases you should start Activity-B as following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Context, Activity-B.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, some_int_code);
```

In Activity-B, finish your as mentioned below:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent());
finish();
```

Above will notify `onActivityResult()` method in your Activity-A. Then you can update anything in this method as following:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == some_int_code) {
       // Write your code here...
    }
}
```

You may read documents [at here for more info about this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use onActivityResult() to notify the first activity of changes.

Is the data bound to some data store? If so, it's probably best to refresh the recyclerview based on an updated query.

Or you could write a singleton class that "manages" this set of data so that other parts of the app can access the data it needs, updates, etc. If you go that route, I might also suggest implementing an observer so that when changes occur on data, any component that is interested receives the update.

All of this is very dependent on your app structure and user interaction.